# Building UITableViewCells in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I am wonder if it is better to build my cells in Interface Builder, or programmatically?  The reason I am leaning toward IB is that my cells are going to have a bit of customization, and it would be much easier this way.

Are their drawbacks to the IB approach?  Also, are there any good tutorials about how to use a cell in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you won't run into performance issues, and building cells in IB is more pleasant than by hand if you have a very customized layout.

The [Table View Programming Guide has a section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) on loading cells from nibs.